# 2nd order differential equation coupled to integro-differential equation in python

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, integral-equations, rootfinding

I'm trying to solve the following equations numerically in python

$$\begin{align}
12\pi\int_0^\infty drf(r)\phi(r)r^4&=E\\
f(r)-\frac{1}{2\mu}\bigg(\frac{d^2\phi(r)}{dr^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{d\phi(r)}{dr} \bigg)+m_\pi\phi(r)&=E\phi(r)
\end{align}
$$

where $f(r)=S\exp(-r^2/b^2)$, while $\mu$ and $m_π$ are constants.

I have tried rewriting the 2nd order differential equation into two first order equations and solving the system of equations with root finding.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import trapz
from scipy.optimize import root
b=1    
S=20    
m=135   
mn = 939.5  
mu = m*mn/(mn+m)

g = (2*mu)

def f(r): 
    return S*np.exp(-r**2/b**2)

def diff(phi,r,E):
    return (phi[1],g*(-E+m)*phi[0]-2/r*phi[1]+g*f(r))

phi0 = [b/m,b/m] #Initial

def phi_fun(E):
    rs = np.linspace(1e-5,50,1000)
    ys = odeint(lambda phi,r: diff(phi,r,E), phi0, rs)
    integral = 12*np.pi*trapz(ys[:,0]*f(rs)*rs**4,rs)
    return integral - E

E_true = root(phi_fun, -2).x

rs = np.linspace(1e-5,50,1000)
ys = odeint(lambda phi,r: diff(phi,r,E_true), phi0, rs)

phi_true = ys[:,0]
plt.plot(rs, phi_true,linewidth=2,label=r'$\phi(r)$')
print("Minimum found at E =",E_true)
```

This does not produce a result I would expect and maybe I have done something wrong. I was thinking about using [IDEsolver](https://idesolver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but I'm not sure how to implement this. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next transformation step would see the system reformulated as a boundary value problem with the additional equations and conditions replacing the integral
$$
I'(r)=12πf(r)ϕ(r)r^4,~~I(0)=0,~~ I(\infty)=E
$$
`scipy` provides `integrate.solve_bvp`, which has a mechanism to handle free parameters like $E$.

Now the equation proceeds from a singular point to an infinite point. At both ends approximations are required if the solution is to stay finite.

- Close to zero the equation is approximately an Euler-Cauchy equation
  $$r^2ϕ''(r)+2rϕ'(r)=0$$
  which has basis solutions $1$ and $r^{-1}$. The second one is to be avoided for finite solutions, so that $ϕ'(a)=0$ is the condition to demand for $a\approx0$, so use that as the left boundary condition with $a\gtrapprox0$.
- For large $r$, other terms in the equation become negligible, the equation is approximately
  $$
  -ϕ''(r)+2μ(m_π-E)ϕ(r)=0
  $$
  You seem to be expecting a negative value for $E$. In that case, the basis solutions are $e^{\pm\sqrt{2μ(m_π+|E|)}r}$. To avoid a diverging behavior also on this end, the positive sign has to be avoided. The basis solution with negative exponents satisfies
  $$
   ϕ'(r)+\sqrt{2μ(m_π+|E|)}ϕ(r)=0.
  $$
  This is then also a suitable boundary condition on the right boundary.

```
def sys(r,u,E):
    y,v,I = u
    dy = v
    dv = g*(-E+m)*y-2/r*v+g*f(r)
    dI = f(r)*r**4*y
    return dy,dv,dI

def bc(ua, ub,E):
    ya,va,Ia = ua
    yb,vb,Ib = ub
    return va, vb+(g*(m+abs(E)))**0.5*yb, Ia, Ib-E

r = np.logspace(-5,0,20)*5
u = [ 0*r,0*r,E*r/r[-1]]
E = -2

res = solve_bvp(sys,bc,r,u,p=[E],tol=1e-4)
print(res.message,", E: ",res.p[0])

plt.plot(res.x,res.y.T,'-+'); 
plt.grid(); plt.legend(r"$\phi$ $\phi'$ $I$".split()); 
plt.show()
```

This works well, reports

```
The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy. , E:  -0.3472387364434603
```

and gives a plot
[image]